# PSoC 1 programming with Kitprog or CY8CKIT-059?

Tags: psoc, cypress-psoc

I am wondering if anyone knows if the Kitprog programmer provided in CY8CKIT-059 supports programming in **ISSP** for PSoC **1** chips?  Similar to Miniprog1/3. Not really worried about debugging for this question.  Cypress documentation on this is extremely scarce.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that KitProg does NOT support ISSP and thus does not support PSoC 1 devices.  It is mainly focused on SWD programming and I2C/UART.  So it is for PSoC 3 ,4 ,5